# iOS simulator keeps crashing with memory access issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, signals, ios-simulator, exc-bad-access

iOS app crashes "randomly" on simulator **inside** Apple API methods. One method that seems to crash more frequently than others is

[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage" inBundle:[MyFramework frameworkBundle] compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];

The signal is

EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x300068)

[image]
This started recently - haven't experienced it in the past.

Also important to note that the crash doesn't happen only when trying to access resources in the bundle. It can happen in ordinary code.

Comment: Sounds like you have a memory smasher or use after free.  Turn on ASan and see if you can find it.  Look at all your crash traces to see what the common ancestor is, etc.

Comment: How do I turn on ASan?

Comment: The address sanitizer option is greyed out in my scheme